# How do I prevent vaadin router from intercepting camunda paths with Vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin, camunda, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I generated a project from the [camunda website](https://start.camunda.com/) with its default options. I use Eclipse IDE and added vaadin using the "Add Starters" function.

I tried adding a vaadin vertical layout in accordance to the [camunda documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/webapps/). However, after I start the project, I get errors like these if I try to reach the camunda platform:

```
com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: Couldn't find route for 'camunda/app/welcome/styles/styles.css'
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:277) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:232) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:198) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:95) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.initializeUIWithRouter(BootstrapHandler.java:1625) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1618) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:508) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1578) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:252) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.ProcessEnginesFilter.applyFilter(ProcessEnginesFilter.java:145) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.filter.AbstractTemplateFilter.doFilter(AbstractTemplateFilter.java:58) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.doFilter(LazyDelegateFilter.java:60) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-7.16.0.jar:7.16.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.headersec.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:89) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:177) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilterSecure(SecurityFilter.java:73) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:57) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.doFilter(LazyDelegateFilter.java:60) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-7.16.0.jar:7.16.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:62) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:60) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.SecurityActions.runWithAuthentications(SecurityActions.java:44) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:60) ~[camunda-webapp-7.16.0-classes.jar:7.16.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

It seems to me that the Vaadin Router intercepts the Url to the camunda platform. How can I make the Router ignore everything that doesn´t have a root annotation in the class with Vaadin Flow?

Update: Thanks to @Simon Martinelli and @cfrick, I solved the problem by adding `vaadin.urlMapping=/vaadin/*` to application.properties.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have this issue and it seems that the Camunda servlet registration is not correct, that's why Vaadin is intercepting.

One workaround is to configure Vaadin to a different base URL:

```
vaadin.url-mapping=/vaadin
```

For 14

```
vaadin.urlMapping=/vaadin
```

Comment: I added the Code in application.properties. The error is the same except the shown route is empty ('').

Comment: Do you navigate to /vaadin

Comment: Yes, I did. I even put the VerticalLayout-class into the same package as the main class. It also has the Route annotation and the String "one" as value, which I typed into the URL as well. Am I missing some annotations?

Comment: What URL are you accessing?

Comment: Older vaadin versions needed that to be written as `urlMapping` (camel instead of kebab case) - could not be yet fixed in the version you are using?

Comment: I use "localhost:8080/vaadin/eins". What Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: @cfrick is right. What Vaadin version are you using? url-mapping is probably 22

Comment: I looked into my pom and the version is 14.8.1

Comment: I've updated my answer